# WCAG Tab index focus object on top position absolute object getting obscured

Tags: javascript, browser, scrollview, wcag

When tabbing from different html tags sometimes the actively focused object is not visible from the screen due to objects that has position absolute, making it on top of what you are focusing therefore unable to see what is currently in focus.

Sample scenario in this [link](https://imgur.com/a/E16kUAX) for reference. "Advance Search tip" link is not visible due to the header set to position absolute. Changing focus to other object that is not visible doesn't change the view. Screen view only changes when the object being focused is not part of the view height of the screen.

Is there any way that everytime you focus objects it will be always on the center of the screen?